# How to add Buttons inside of MapControl Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to put two Buttons in my MapControl, one to zoom in, and other to zoom out, here's my CS file with a code,what i did here i use the 
`MapControl1.ZoomLevel = 15;` , but how i can put this inside a button?

```
public async void mapas2()
    {
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition geoposition = null;
        try
        {
            geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog ms = new MessageDialog("Erro GPS, Por favor, acesse as configurações de seu Windows Phone," + Environment.NewLine +
            "na opção LOCALIZAÇÃO e habilite o Serviço de Localização");
            ms.ShowAsync();


        }
        MapControl1.Center = geoposition.Coordinate.Point;
        MapControl1.ZoomLevel = 15;

        MapIcon mapIcon = new MapIcon();

        mapIcon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.25, 0.9);
        mapIcon.Location = geoposition.Coordinate.Point;
        mapIcon.Title = "Você está aqui....";

        MapControl1.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place these buttons with your map control in one `Grid` in XAML, so the will look like they're on the map.

Example:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Maps:MapControl />
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Margin="24">
        <Button Content="+" 
                Margin="12" 
                MinWidth="40" />
        <Button Content="-" 
                Margin="12" 
                MinWidth="40"  />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, one more question, how can i make a zoom with a MapControl1.ZoomLevel inside the button handler?

Comment: Just call `MapControl1.ZoomLevel++;` :)

Answer (score 0):

Just few more lines to Łukasz Rejman answer

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15">
<Button x:Name="ZooOut" Content="-"  Margin="5"  MinWidth="60" MinHeight="60" Tapped="ZooOut_Tapped"  />
<Button x:Name="ZoomIn" Content="+" Margin="5" MinWidth="60" MinHeight="60" Tapped="ZoomIn_Tapped" />
</StackPanel>
```

Button Tapped Event:

```
private void ZoomIn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel < 20)
        {
            if (CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel > 19)
                CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel = 20;
            else
                CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel++;
        }   
    }

    private void ZooOut_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel > 1)
        {
            if (CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel < 2)
                CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel = 1;
            else
                CustomMapControl.ZoomLevel--;
        }
    }
```